# Edit height of UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uitoolbar

In `viewDidLoad` I'm setting the height to be different from the standard 44 points. I want it to be 35 points, for example. Using the code:

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, frame.size.height-35.f, frame.size.width, 35.f)];
```

and checking the frame's dimensions before and after I get a printout of:

```
Before: {{0, 623}, {375, 44}}
After:  {{0, 632}, {375, 35}}
```

However when checking for this in the simulator, the height is constantly 44 points. The same is true when I use a large height value like 350, I get:

```
Before: {{0, 623}, {375, 44}}
After:  {{0, 317}, {375, 350}}
```

I have thought of subclassing `UIToolbar` and creating my own but `UIToolbar` on `UINavigationController` is a readonly property. What else may I try?

Comment: Have you tried setting it's frame in `viewWillAppear:` ?

Comment: Yes. Though, `viewWillAppear:` is actually called after `viewDidLoad` so I don't think this is necessary even if it did allow it to work.

Comment: Overriding `layoutSubviews` in a subclass seems the best bet to me. I tried with many possible solutions, but adding an `@implementation` block for `UIToolBar` and overriding `layoutSubviews` is the only working solution I have found, yet.

Comment: This is possible even if UIToolbar on UINavigationController is a readonly property?

Comment: Thanks, @n00bProgrammer! Creating a category on UIToolbar and overriding said method `layoutSubviews` did the trick! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. Even I learned something new today, thanks to you. :)

Comment: It doesn't come without its own pitfalls, however. I'm now stuck with placing any UIBarButtonItems individually which is not fun. :/

Comment: Luckily for me, I'm just treating this toolbar as just another view anyway. It's hardly FOR UIBarButtonItems.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the steps below,

1. Subclass the UIToolbar
2. Override the DrawRect
3. specify the new behaviour of the toolbar

Hope this may help you.

Comment: While subclassing would be nice, I can't assign my subclass of `UIToolbar` to a readonly property (which is the case on `UINavigationController`). If you can think of a way around this, that would be helpful. My goal is to have my Toolbar persist between view controllers without having it's content/context change.